# Swift : boundingRectWithSize return wrong height for a multiline label

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I'm using an extension on the String class to get the height needed to display my string in a multiline label.

```
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)

        let option = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)

        let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: option, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        print("ex width \(boundingBox.width)")
        print("ex height \(boundingBox.height)")
        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

I'm calling it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let myRandomString = "My baby looks like she's ashamed and wants to apologise for something bad she did."
let labelWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-16
let labelHeight = myRandomString.heightWithConstrainedWidth(labelWidth,font: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17))
```

and I get :

```
ex width 359.0
ex height 40.57421875
```

But when I use the view debuging option of xcode I get this :
[image]

And this is how my UILabel is setup :
[image]

As you can see my width is correct (I'm forcing it) but my height is incorrect and I can't figure out why.

Thanks and regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

For multiline only use `.UsesLineFragmentOrigin`.